# iOS How fix button at the bottom UITableView Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have one issue, i want to fix a button at the bottom of `UITableView`, which will stay at the place when user will scroll.

Example:

[image]

How i can do this?

**UPDATE:**

My storyboard:

[image]

Comment: If you want to stay `UIButton` at bottom then why you add it inside `UITableView` footer. You can add `UIButton` at bottom of your `ViewController`

Comment: @Kuldeep yes i add at the bottom new view with button, but this still scroll.

Comment: If you add your `UITableView` and `UIButton` separately in `storyBoard` then there's no possibility of your `UIButton` scroll. Please upload your `StoryBoard` screen.

Comment: Are you using a UIViewController or a UITableViewController? The latter won't work, as far as I know, since you need to add the button as a sibling of the tableview and not as a child of it. If you add it as a child it will probably appear in the tableview's header or footer.

Comment: @Kuldeep update, storyboard in question

Comment: OK, just saw your screenshot. Yes, you're using a UITableViewController. Use a UIViewController and add a tableview and a button to it.

Comment: @andlin i use UITableViewController

Comment: @Kuldeep UITableViewController

Comment: As you can see in your screenshot, your button (or rather its parent view) has been added to the tableview, which means it will scroll with the tableview. UITableViewController doesn't support adding additional views to the same level as the tableview, since the root view of the viewcontroller is the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add it to the tableview. Place it under the tableview and and pin its bottom to the viewcontroller's view and the button's top to the bottom of the tableview

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place that button at bottom side. make sure that you place that button on one level up from `UITableView` in view hierarchy and set contentInset like this,

```
self.tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 'your button height', right: 0)
```